# Some BLOB cannot be saved to SQL but some can

Tags: php, sql, image, blob

I'm trying to save some images to SQL by using BLOB type in SQL but I got trouble when some images (my images are in base64 format and have been decode to BLOB) cannot save to SQL but the other can.
[MY SQL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofeZo.png)

```js
saveFile = function () {
 //window.open(app.stage.toDataURL());
    var dataUrl = app.stage.toDataURL();
 //var name= jQuery("#name").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveFile.php",
        data: { image : dataUrl },
        success: function(data){
           alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php
//echo DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
//echo $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ];
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . DS . 'joomla' );

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$input = new JInput;
$post = $input->getArray($_POST);
$user = JFactory::getUser();

//echo $user->id;   

if(isset($_POST['image'])){
    $id = $user->id;
    $url = $post['image'];

    //echo $url;
    $image = base64_decode($url);

    echo $image;

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $columns = array('id_user', 'image'); // add more table columns here
    $values = array($db->quote($id), $db->quote($image)); // add more values here

    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('image_table2'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    //$db->query(); // Use for Joomla 2.5
    $db->execute(); // Use for Joomla 3.x
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, after 2 hours researching i found that base64_decode have problem with "very long" base64 code, so the solution is

`$image = ""; 
        for ($i=0; $i < ceil(strlen($url)/256); $i++) 
            $image = $image . base64_decode(substr(str_replace(' ', '+', $url),$i*256,256));`